# Centered Menu with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my menu, but I don't know why it isn't working. Can someone help me?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
  background: #19c589;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  color: #2f3036;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #19c589;
  color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
  display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #19c589;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
  }
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button" />
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About ￬</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Portfolio ￬</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web & User Interface Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you include your css in the question you’re more likely to get a fast response

Comment: What exactly is wrong nothing is wrong with your code.

Comment: all code are here: https://jsfiddle.net/629pyfvj/, i try center menu on middle thanks for help

Comment: Please include all code **in the question itself**. Don't make us go off site to find the actual problem in the CSS.

Comment: @JonP I've moved the code into a snippet, so you don't have to go off site. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring all of your `ul` elements as `position:absolute`. You will need to change your `ul id="menu"` item to static positioning, and also give it a defined width since you are defining the width of your `li a` elements. Check your [updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/629pyfvj/13/). Simply add the following to your css:

```
#menu {
  width:705px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  position:static;
}
```

Comment: hi, on responsive, the menu hidding... thanks for help

Comment: Add this to your media query: `ul {max-width:100%;}`. The fiddle has been updated